# Clear out or reset google analytics ecommerce

Tags: php, google-analytics

I've just implemented Web Tracking for a webshop, and now I have 18 testing transactions that I need to get rid off..
I read the documentations, and it says that I have to make a new *negative* transactions with the same ID, and that I have to do *-1* on the quantity of each product.
But only the total cart value and only one of the products was detected at the first tests.. So I have like 4000.00 i total cart revenue on a transaction, but only one product -- delivery -- at 111.00...

How do I do *-1* on a product that's not even listed?
Is there a way to reset the whole ecommerce tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse an order or transaction, you will create and load a duplicate receipt page that contains negative values for transaction total, tax, shipping, and item quantity.  The values are the same as the value in the transaction you want to remove.

For example, if the the original transaction total is $111, the duplicate entry will have -$111 as the transaction total. Google Analytics records this negative value and applies it against your totals, effectively reversing the transaction.

Its not really removeing it in my opinion as canceling it out.